# Custom Widget and Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, widget, wordpress-shortcode

Can someone tell me how I can place short code into custom widget. I can not figure out how to add editor so short code will be rendered and not just display code. ie [events] on the front end?  I created textarea in widget but textarea does not run short code?

Answer (score 0):

before showing text in the widget run trough filter

```
$formatted_content = apply_filters('the_content', $your_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the text or Custom HTML widget when adding this to your functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```